# Call child component method in parent and visa versa

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, typescript, reactjs

how can I call a parent components methods from child or visa versa.

I'm using reactjs and typescript in spfx webpart.

Or should I use helper classes to call methods of another classes from anywhere?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

there are very few information you give but I guess your problem will be solved by giving CallBack functions to your ChildElement like this:

parentElement.ts

```
public render(){
    ...
        <MyChildComponent 
            optionsA={this.props.OptionsA} //give some properties to your Component
            optionsSelected={this.optionsSelected.bind(this)} //give a CallBack
         />
    ...
}

...

private optionsSelected(selection){
// DO SOMETHING
}
    ...
```

childElement.ts

```
public render() {
...
    <myChildDropDown
       onChanged={(event) => this.props.optionsSelected(event)}
     />
...
}
```